# What command line tool can I install on a Mac to play music?

Tags: command-line, music

I want to install a tool different from `mplayer` on a mac to play music. I want to be able to play mp3 music files that are in a folder, either in order or randomly. I.e. I want to do something like

```
player files/*
player -shuffle files/*
```

with some key shortcuts to pause and skip to the next title.

What other command line too is there I can try?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a command line tool installed. The command is afplay and you run it by typing:

```
afplay /path/to/audiofile.mp3
```

This link describes better how to use this tool. https://osxdaily.com/2009/10/27/play-mp3s-and-other-music-from-the-command-line/

Comment: This command cannot be used. Two requirements, which I mentioned in the question, are missing: 1. I want to be able to play a list of files (i.e. use `afplay folder_with_many_files/*` and 2. I want to be able to shuffle the files. But nevermind, I think I will just create a tool myself.